# How buffer is helpful in Async Appender while using in log4J

Tags: java, log4j

I am using asyncappender in my application with four rollingfileappenders under it.
I am unable to get the details of the buffer used in it.
I need clarifications on:

1. How the buffer works?
2. How to flush the buffer after the events in it are logged?
3. Can we do this flushing using the configuration file(.xml file) or do we need to code in our java class?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a queue to which logging events are placed. There is a dispatcher thread which takes events from the queue and publish it to underlying appenders.

2, 3. It will flushed automatically at some point by the thread.

You cannot control flush manually, I think it is by design, since it is implementation details.

I suppose the async appender doesn't have any sense for file appenders, because usually they work fast enough. I think the main purpose of it - is to wrap around database or smtp appenders which could have temporary network glitches.

Comment: My understanding from your answer is that, Buffer will be automatically flushed and there wont be any issues like overflowing of the buffer when we use this asynappender.

Comment: Of course there are issues. It will block or drop events. Please read the `org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender#getBlocking()` documentation: "Gets whether appender should block calling thread when buffer is full. If false, messages will be counted by logger and a summary message appended after the contents of the buffer have been appended."